# Past tense progression

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

> My mother was raised in a family that **had**  placed extreme importance on filial piety.

Is ***had*** superfluous, wrong, or correct?

I can see arguments in both directions:

1. Perfect past (*raised*) requires pluperfect (*had placed*).
2. Reflexive participle makes *raised* imperfect, even though it's a completed action, therefore *placed* is sufficient.

Comment: Not much to do with grammar. Both are acceptable. The two versions do not quite mean the same thing, though.

Comment: The reading with *had* implies that the *placing* was a one-time action, distinctly preceding the *raising,* which seems less plausible than that the placing and the raising were both ongoing processes and simultaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For action that began in the past and was completed in the past, use the past simple tense.

- I was raised in a small town where people went to church every Sunday.
- My mother was raised in a family that placed extreme importance on religion.

Use the past perfect tense to indicate that action was completed in the past, before another action happened.

- She had already left when we arrived.
- After I had cleaned the windows I decided to take a shower.

In your sentence, the past simple tense is the correct form: "My mother was raised in a family that placed extreme importance on filial piety."  "had" in this case is not superfluous, it's wrong.

Comment: "Had" isn't *necessarily* wrong -- it would be fine if they had ceased to do so at some point. But that's probably not the intended meaning.